# Are these two tags the same: equipment & coffee-machines?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm thinking on these two tags, [equipment](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) and [coffee-machines](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coffee-machines) for a while. Are these two the same thing? If not, what's the difference?

- coffee-machines: This sounds like an automated machine used **to brew** coffee.
- equipment: This sounds like a manual equipment used while **preparing** coffee.

If it sounds, I opt to include such text as tag guidance.

In this case, "a manual equipment **to brew** coffee" is missing, maybe it can be added as a separate tag.

Another solution may be to add a tag synonym and tag everything as an equipment.

Comment: I agree with your definitions, although this leaves an obvious gap. What about manual machines used to brew coffee? I'm thinking things like cafetieres, mokka pots, and the like.

Comment: @NickUdell coffee-brewers or brewing-equipment?

Comment: The tag wiki for both of those tags were indeed really lacking. Since you mentioned it, I took a stab at updating and expanding per my thoughts. Of course, please do feel free to update or clarify as you see fit. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

The tags [equipment](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) and [coffee-machines](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coffee-machines) are certainly different enough to remain separate. By counter-example, I would consider an *espresso tamper* and a *grinder* as "equipment" but I couldn't consider tagging as "coffee-machine". Both could in a sense be considered as "machines", and they are for "coffee", I wouldn't consider either a "coffee-machine" as such.

Perhaps the [equipment](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) tag is too broad, but I think it's okay as a catch-all. It can include anything that is in [coffee-machines](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coffee-machines), plus lots more. As was pointed out in question and comments, there are other coffee preparation equipment that aren't "machines", but there are already more specific tags for many, such as [french-press](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french-press), [moka](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moka), and [pour-over](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pour-over). There are also more general tags like [drip-brew](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drip-brew) that isn't specific to machine or manual.

I'm happy with the current state of affairs, but if there's something unclear, let's update the tag wiki to be more helpful. If there's something missing, please do feel free to create a new tag!